# Inheritance with EF Code First - Table per Concrete Type (TPC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I created such a kind of [Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) structure as shown below:

[image]

Here are the entities used here:

```
public abstract class BaseModel : MyOtherBaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Project
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IconUrl { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties ####################
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}


[Table("Tool")]
public class Tool : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ToolBrand { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties ####################
    //public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}


[Table("Priority")]
public class Priority : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PriorityCode { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties ####################
    //public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

At this point I am confused about the issues below:

1) Can I use Id for Tool and Priority entities? And will it be absolutely unnecessary?

2) I use FK (ProjectId) and related table Project in the BaseModel class. But, as the ProjectId columns will be created in the Tool and Priority tables, how can the relation be created? May there be any problem?

3) If I do not prefer Fluent API, should I add Tool and Priority entities besides BaseModel entity in the context? Because in some resources the child classes are added while in some others not. Which one is true?

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseModel> BaseModel { get; set; }
    // ? public DbSet<Tool> Tool { get; set; }
    // ? public DbSet<Priority> Priority { get; set; }
}
```

If there is any problem regarding to this usage could you also please let me know? Thanks...

Comment: How is this TPC if your Tool and Priority tables in db don’t have the columns from BaseModel?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Sorry, I do not understand what do you mean? Is it related to point 1-2-3?

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood you. I thought that diagram is the db schema where it may just be a class diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you design classes you should be aware of what the classes really represent.

Your `DbSet<...>` represents one table your database. The class inside the `DbSet` represents the columns of this table as non-virtual properties, and the relations between the tables as virtual properties.

It seems to me that you want two tables in your database: a table with `Tools` and a table with `Priorities`. You currently think that some columns of `Tools` are also in `Priorities`. Therefore you intend to make a common base class of which you have no better name than `BaseModel`.

The fact that you can't invent a proper name for the common base class should warn you that maybe there is nothing really common between those two. Are you sure, that if you describe a `Tool`, that is is not an incident that it has some properties with the same name and type as a `Priority`

For example. If you would define rows of `Tools` and rows `Priorities`, you would say that every `Tool` is used in a `Project`, and every `Priority` is the priority of a `Project`. This is part of the design of your system. According your definition it is meaningless to have `Tools` without its `Project`

Even so, according to your definition, every tool should have a "method of unique Identification", you decided to use an integer Id for this. Similarly you decided to have an integer Id for priorities. However, is it intrinsic to a row in your `Tool` table that the type of the identification equals the type of identification of a Priority? Would you want your design be worthless if someone told you that a `Tool` has a Guid Id and an `Priority` has an integer Id?

No of course not: your design should be so robust that small changes in your database tables should lead to small changes in your design!

### Which properties should be in the base class

> 1) Can I use Id for Tool and Priority entities?

Answer: Yes you can put the Id in the base class and omit it from the derived classes. However, this would add a constraint that every derived type should have the same name and type for the column in the table that represents the Id.

Hence: if you don't want to limit yourself to this: don't do this, remove the Id from the base class and put it in the derived class. If later someone decides a small change to rename the column, or give it a different type your changes will be similar small.

Of course this is also for all other properties: if they are identical "by coincidence", put the values in the derived class. If it is typical something that both `Tools` and `Priorities` have in common, put it in the base class.

It is not easy for me to detect similarities between Tools of a Project and Priorities of a Project, so I'll switch to a different example.

Suppose you have a database with Teachers and Students. Some properties are unique for the Teachers, and some are unique for the Students. But they also have something in common that is not by coincidence: Teachers and Students are both Persons, with a Name, a Birthday, possibly an Address etc. If later someone decides that an Address has an extra field indicating the GPS coordinates of the address, then you'll only have to change one class.

> Conclusion: only put properties in the base class that are intrinsic common to all derived classes, not by coincidence

### Where to put the foreign key?

According to your design, both Tools and Priorities are things belonging to a Project. If  after the previous step you decided that this is the only thing they have in common, then you'll seldom take a bunch of objects that contain both Tools and Priorities.

In the school database it would be quite normal to put Students and Teachers into a bunch of Persons, where every Person would have an Address, and in every Address would be living zero or more Persons (one-to-many)

```
// this will be a row in a table, hence it has an Id
class Address
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string ZipCode {get; set;}
     public string Street {get; set;}
     ...

     // on every address live zero or more Persons (one-to-many)
     public virtual ICollection <Person> Persons {get; set;}
}

// this will not be a row in a separate table, hence it has no ID
class Person
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public DateTime Birthday {get; set;}
     ...
     // every Person lives at an Address, using foreign key
     public int AddressId {get; set;}
     public virtual Address Address {get; set;}
}

class Teacher : Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
}
class Student: Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

So you will have three tables: Addresses, Teachers, Students. Both Teachers and Students will have the properties of a Person. They both live at exactly one Address.

See how little changes need to be made if we decide to add a column to a Teacher, or a Person? How little needs to be changes if you want a Teacher Id to be a GUID, or the Address.Id be a String (expect changes in primary Key of Address and foreign key inside Person). See how little needs to be changed if you want to add a new type of Person: a Parent?

> Conclusion: if you have a base class where every derived class should have a reference to an item in a different table: put the foreign key in the base class. However, if this relation is not intrinsic to all derived items, put the foreign key in the derived classes.

### 3 should I add entities besides BaseModel entity in the context?

Remember: every DbSet in your DbContext will become a table. If you don't specify Tools and Priorities as separate tables, you won't be using [Table per concreate class (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) but [table per hierarchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph): both Tools and Priorities will be in one table

I seldom use TPH because of all unused null values I get in my tables.

If you most often will ask for "Teachers that ..." and "Students which ...", you should keep them in separate tables. The columns of the base class are also in these separate tables.

If you most often will ask for "Persons who ...", where the Persons might be Students or Teachers, consider using [table per type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt): a Persons table, and a Teachers table with a foreign key to the Persons tables, as well as a Students table with a foreign key. All base class properties are in the Persons table.

It is easy to see that if you ask for "Persons that..." TPT will only query one table, whild for TPC you'll need to query the Teachers table as well as the Students table and concatenate the result.

However if you ask for "Students that ..." TPT will need to join the Persons table and the Students table. TPC is here faster: only one table is accessed.

Comment: Many thanks for your perfect and detailed explanations. Regarding to your answer >>>

Comment: **1)** I gave the related table name by mistake, sorry. I corrected its name as it should be >>> Project :)

Comment: **2)** Regarding to the Conclusion of your 2nd comment, I checked the derived classes in the database and obtained that FK relation was also created for these derived classses although I have not added FK to these classes (only added to the base class as shown on my question). In this scene should I put the foreign key in the derived classes?

Comment: **3)** Regarding to 3rd point, I decided to use TPC and in this case I think I should add Tool and Priority entities to my DbContext and do not add BaseModel entity. After that there will be 2 tables are created in the database. Is that true?

Comment: First make your design correct. Decide whether you want TPC, TPT etc, and especially: why do you want this kind of derivation and not the other one? Why derivation and not aggregation: which queries and updates do you most? Read the links about the TPC TPT. See whether the code you implemented really does this kind of tables. Use proper fluent API to make sure that the relations between the tables are as you wanted them